# Why doesn't Eclipse do a Build in a Makefile project when the previous Build failed?

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have a Makefile project in Eclipse CDT, which is comprised of dozens of source files. I normally build the project with the `-j` option, so the `make` does parallel builds. Sometimes I need the serial build. Thus, I defined two configurations, differing in that option.

If an error occurs while doing a parallel build, then sometimes it is hard to follow the diagnostics messages due to `make`'s interleaved output from all processes. So next thing I do is try the serial build configuration.

The problem is that unless I actually change a file, or clean the project, no build is performed. as Eclipse assumed nothing has changed (which is technically right, but in a C/C++ Project, it will know the build was not complete and attempt to rebuild *[at least IIRC]*).

How can I make Eclipse to run the make command if I changed a configuration, but not a file?

Comment: Why do you need the serial build? Also with new enough make you can use [`-O`/`--output-sync`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel-Output) option to get synchronized output even with parallel builds.

Comment: @EtanReisner - I explained why in my question. I am not sure what version of make the toolchain we use has, but I will give your tip a try.

Comment: You said you use it to debug a broken build but also implied that you had *other* reasons for using it. If you don't have other reasons for using it then you can ignore that question. But in either case the target the failed to build should *always* get rebuilt when you run `make` again since the target doesn't exist. If that doesn't happen then something else is *very* wrong.

Comment: The reason to run Serial Builds is just for getting readable diagnostics. Just checked, the `make` utility used with ARM's DS-5 toolchain is *GNU Make 3.81*. It seems that it does not support the `-O` option. The problem is not with the Make utility itself, skipping the build, but with Eclipse not starting it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, 3.81 is too old for `-O`. I believe it needs 4.0+ (and possibly 4.1 for some output options). And yes, I realize your specific issue was an Eclipse issue but I don't use Eclipse and solving the underlying issue would avoid even having the Eclipse issue. Anyway, the issue is that Eclipse won't even start the build at all?

Comment: Yes, it won't start it (at least it does not *seem* to do so) unless I make *some* change to the files (add then delete a space, for example).